# If there are an A bag and a B bag

Tags: sentence-meaning

I have an A bag and not a B bag, and I just say 'I have a bag,' then can it be wrong because 'a bag' indicates the B bag?

Comment: Be more specific.

Comment: At least in American English, the indefinite article **a** and the letter **A** usually have different pronunciations, so "A bag" and "a bag" don't sound the same. Also, a bag labelled "A" would usually be called "bag A", not "A bag".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just tell someone you have a bag there's no information conveyed about what particular bag (or bags) you might have. As long as you have some bag this is a true statement and correct English. The construction "a bag" can sometimes mean just one, sometimes at least one.

If one of the bags is named "A" then your listener might be confused. You should probably say "I have the A bag".

Answer (score 0):

No.

The word "an" is just a pronunciation variant of "a".  When you say "a" followed by a vowel sound, an "n" sound is inserted.

> John gave me an enormous banana.  Now I have a banana.

This is quite correct, and the banana refered to in the second sentence is understood to be the enormous one of the first sentence. You don't say "an banana" even if it is an enormous one.

Note that the is a pronunciation variation in "the". Before vowels it is often pronounced as "thee" but there is no spelling difference.